# c# how do i prevent one specific character from being added to a text file

Tags: c#, textbox, streamwriter

I have a program where the user enters data into a text box, and then presses a button which adds it to a text file using stream writer. How do I make an error appear when the user tries to enter the character "~". It breaks the entire program, since its used to seperate different data in the text files.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: are you searching for string.Replace()?

Comment: I don't know what to try, I don't know c#, i've been using tutorials (don't ask why I need to make this, it's for school). I need to display an error message using messagebox.show if the user enters "~".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the user input string if it contains the character that you want to disallow.
Like below,

```
string userInput= myTextBox.Text;
if( userInput.Contains('~') )
    MessageBox.Show("This ~ char is not allowed");
...
//write to file
```